# Sending FormData with Ajax Post Call results in Get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple form that I'm trying to send via POST but I can't for the life of me get it working.

I initially load the form contents using AJAX,

```js
$(function() {
  var arg = {
    "operation": "upload",
    "step": "0"
  };
  fetchForm(arg, "#form");
});
```

Which then calls this simple bit of code:

```js
function fetchForm(arg, resultTarget){
  $.post("./form.php", arg, function(data){
    $(resultTarget).html(data);
  }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError){
    alert(throwError);
  }).done( function(){ 
   afterAjax();
  });
}
```

Which get's the form from the server and loads the contents. I have a few input fields and submit button. On previous forms I would quickly process the form and POST it to the server again.

```js
function processForm(){
 var form = $("#form form").serialize();
 fetchForm(form, "#form");
}
```

However because I'm attaching a BASE 64 URL image I'm using a form data object which is then stored in a preview element:

```js
function handleFiles() {
  var preview = $("#previewImg")[0];
  var file = $("#fileUpload")[0].files[0];

  preview.setAttribute("name", file.name);
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

function customProcessForm() {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("operation", $("#operation")[0].val);
  data.append("step", $("#step")[0].val);
  data.append("u_stuNumber", $("#number")[0]);
  data.append("u_fileName", $("#previewImg")[0].getAttribute("name"));
  data.append("u_dataURL", $("#previewImg")[0].src);


  console.log("Button Clicked");
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "./form.php",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  });

}
```

When the image is uploaded I read the file, set the preview source and name to the image. Which is then retrieved when the the user selects submit.

However I get the following in my console,

```
jquery.min.js:4 XHR failed loading: POST "https://[url]/form.php"
```

What's even more bizzare is that my variables appear as a get message:

```
image.html?operation=upload&step=1&u_stuNumber=Foobar&photos=IMG_1435.JPG
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT: Here's the HTML Form:

```html
<form roll="form" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
  <input id="operation" type="hidden" name="operation" value="upload">
  <input id="step" type="hidden" name="step" value="1">
  <fieldset id="residentInfo">
    <legend>Your Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="number" class="sr-only">Your Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="number" type="text" name="u_stuNumber" placeholder="Your Name" autofocus required>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="issueInfo">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 text-center">
      <label for="previewImg" class="sr-only">Problem Location</label>
      <img src="assets/images/preview.png" alt="preview" id="previewImg" name="u_container" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileUpload" accept="image/*" aria-label="Photo Upload" name="photos">
      <br>For some users the preview image may appear sideways. It will be corrected on submission.
      <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="customProcessForm()">Test</button>
    </div>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your problems come down to `onclick="customProcessForm()"`.

When you click the submit button:

1. The onclick handler is triggered
2. The Ajax request fires
3. The JS finishes
4. The *form submits*
5. The Ajax request is canceled
6. The browser loads a new page (the result of submitting the form)

You need to cancel the default behaviour of the form.

The quick and dirty way to do that is to add `return false` to the `onclick` attribute.

The sensible way to do that would be to:

1. Set up the form so it works without JS. Give it a sensible `action`, `method` and `enctype`
2. Get rid of the `onclick` attribute
3. Use JavaScript `($('...').on('submit', someFunction)` to bind your event handler
4. Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour of the form when the JS runs

Comment: That's it! The quick and dirty way is working for now, thanks for the advice. I've been scratching my head about this for hours, I'll work on properly doing the form when I get the DB stuff working.